# Compare files with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compare, text-files

I would like to know how could I compare two files (line by line) (*.xml, *.m,*.txt,...etc) using MATLAB.

```
file1 = 'toto.xml';
file2 = 'titi.xml';
```

I'm looking for a MATLAB function (by command line) that returns me true/false or list of diff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use MATLAB's **system** command with **fc** if you are in Windows:

```
file_name_1 = 'file1.txt';
file_name_2 = 'file2.txt';

[status,result] = system(['fc ' file_name_1 ' ' file_name_2]);
```

Here *status* will be 0 if files are equal and 1 if not. Furthermore *result* will have the diff result if files differ.

For other operating systems you can use similar commands such as **cmp** in Unix instead of **fc**.

**UPDATE:**

For cross-platform compatibility you may try the following:

```
file_1 = javaObject('java.io.File', 'file1.txt');
file_2 = javaObject('java.io.File', 'file2.txt');
is_equal = javaMethod('contentEquals','org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils',...
                      file_1, file_2)
```

Comment: +1. `cmp` does byte-by-byte comparison; you want `diff` on Unix for line-wise comparison.

Comment: @upperBound: is it shell command ? so it can run under all OS?

Comment: It is a shell command. "fc" is Windows specific. For Unix use "diff" as Andrew pointed out.

Comment: @lola: I updated my answer to add cross-platform compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

first change the text file to string, then use strcmp function of matlab.

```
text1 = fileread('test.txt');
text2 = fileread('testcp.txt');
strcmp(text1, text2)
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the only diffing tool in MATLAB is [`visdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/visdiff.html) which does not return any information, but displays a window with both files side-by-side and highlights the different lines.

Comment: @lola: And as I said, as far as I know, it doesn't exist. You could write your own program though.

Comment: jacob, using visdiff, how could I get text saying that there is diff between files ?

Answer (score 0):

First you can read both files by lines:

```
fid1 = fopen(file1, 'r');
fid2 = fopen(file2, 'r');

lines1 = textscan(fid1,'%s','delimiter','\n');
lines2 = textscan(fid2,'%s','delimiter','\n');
lines1 = lines1{1};
lines2 = lines2{1};


fclose(fid1);
fclose(fid2);
```

You will have 2 cell arrays `lines1` and `lines2`. You can compare the whole arrays with

```
tf = isequal(lines1,lines2);
```

Comparing lines is not so obvious and depends on your need. What you want to do if number of lines is different? For example, to find which lines from file2 exist in file1 (independently of order) you can do:

```
[idx1 idx2] = ismember(lines1,lines2);
idx2(idx2==0) = [];
```

`idx1` will be logical index representing lines in file1 that have the same lines in file2. `idx2` will be numeric (position) index of where those lines located in file2 (the first occurrence).

If the number of lines are the same:

```
idx_same_lines = strcmp(lines1,lines2);
```

Comment: when I use [idx1 idx2] = ismember(lines1,lines2);  I got an error :Input must be cell arrays of strings.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I updated the code with two new lines. Now `lines1` and `lines2` should be cell arrays of strings. Please try again.

Comment: thanks yuk, but I would like to browse file2 to check that 'toto []'(which is available in file) is also available in file2

Comment: For visual browsing use `visdiff` as in @Jacob's answer. To just tell if the files are the same or different, you can write a function based on my answer (see the line with isequal).

Answer (score 0):

In case that you have a file (or a path) with spaces (like **c:\my folder\myfile.m**), wrap the file name with quotation mark (") in the DOS command. Note that the apostrophe is still needed:

```
file_name_1 = 'file 1.txt';
file_name_2 = 'file 2.txt';

[status,result] = system(['fc ', '"', file_name_1, '" "', file_name_2, '"']);
```

Alternatively, you can put the quotation mark as soon as you define the variable of the file name:

```
file_name_1 = '"file 1.txt"';
file_name_2 = '"file 2.txt"';

[status,result] = system(['fc ' file_name_1 ' ' file_name_2]);
```