# How to programatically save MATLAB comparison results from visdiff and reload them into the GUI or save as HTML?

Tags: html, matlab, diff, mat-file

The [comparison tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/comparing-files-and-folders.html) `visdiff(file1.m,file2.m)` report displays the files `file1.m` and `file2.m` side by side, and highlights the lines that do not match.

In the GUI that pops up you could click and `Save comparison report as HTML`.

You could have [assigned the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401538/compare-files-within-matlab), for example, `myDiff = visdiff(file1.m,file2.m);`

And then [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) `myDiff` as a `.mat` with `save(myVisDiff,myDiff);`, which by definition is not an HTML, and I do not know how I would load it back to be visually inspected.

How could I programatically save the `HTML` as `HTML` produced by `visdiff(file1.m,file2.m)` or visually display the same GUI originally created by visdiff if `myDiff` were stored as a .mat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you received from `visdiff` is HTML, everything left to do is to write it to a file:

```
fid=fopen('diff.html')
fwrite(fid,myDiff,'char')
flose(fid)
```

If you wish you could also use the matlab built-in browser to display the results:

```
web(['text://',myDiff])
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but this might help you:

```
comparison = visdiff('test.m', 'test2.m') 
fp = fopen('report.html', 'w');
fprintf(fp, '%s', comparison);
fclose(fp);
```